# Синхронизация времени, сервер и клиент

Tags: backend, синхронизация, ntp

Когда клиент проходит авторизацию на сервере он получает токен доступа который валидный некоторое время. У меня вопрос как сервер задает это время, это локальное время сервера или запросы к NTP серверам? Потому что если локальное то изменение даты и времени на сервере может убить систему а если NTP то постоянные запросы от сервера к другому серверу занимают время

Comment: Токенов огромное множество. Если вы про jwt токен пишете, то его проверяет обычно сервер. Если злоумышленник имеет доступ к серверу и может переводить время, то в этом случае уязвимость токена не самая большая проблема.

Comment: @tym32167 да нет, администратор может) начитался о ntp, но запрос к другому серверу - время, да и защиты в ntp не увидел, вообще не понял что мешает совершить атаку man in the middle на запрос от сервера к public ntp серверу

Comment: mitm на ntp по моему вообще отдельная тема. Тут программисту токенов явно делать нечего, безопасность сетей удел сисадминов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте различные источники времени. Если у вас сервер возвращает/задаёт/вычисляет время, то клиент уже только использует его и не важно какое у клиента сейчас время. На счёт актуальности времени на сервере это не задача программиста, поскольку он считает время на сервере верным, а задача администратора этого сервера.